# Reasoner to inference rdf:type in JENA API

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, owl

Hello I am using Jena API to load RDF/XML file from local directory. Below is the RDF/XML file:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/sample#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/sample> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/sample> rdf:type owl:Ontology .


#################################################################
#
#    Classes
#
#################################################################


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/sample#Child1

:Child1 rdf:type owl:Class ;

    rdfs:subClassOf :SubClass2 .



###  http://www.semanticweb.org/sample#Child2

:Child2 rdf:type owl:Class ;

    rdfs:subClassOf :SubClass2 .



###  http://www.semanticweb.org/sample#SubClass1

:SubClass1 rdf:type owl:Class .



###  http://www.semanticweb.org/sample#SubClass2

:SubClass2 rdf:type owl:Class,
                :SubClass1 .
```

object and property relations of the above RDF/XML is as follows:

- There are two classes under thing: SubClass1 and SubClass2.
- SubClass2 further has two children classes: Class1 and Class2
- Additionally SubClass2 is of type (i.e., rdf:type) SubClass1

So by inference, even Child1 & Child2 should be of type SubClass1. Right? Please let me know if I am wrong.

And I used several Reasoners with Jena API to extract all the classes of type "SubClass1", but everytime the output is only one entity (i.e., SubClass1)

I am using the sample code mentioned in this link (Section 2): http://opentox.org/data/documents/development/RDF%20files/JavaOnly/query-reasoning-with-jena-and-sparql

Please someone let me know what is the best reasoner to use for this use case? Appreciate your help.

Comment: No, that can not be inferred by RDFS or OWL DL reasoning. The RDFS rule combining `rdf:type` and `rdfs:subClassOf` is `[(s rdf:type C), (C rdfs:subClassOf D) => (s rdf:type D)]`. What you would need is something like `[(C rdfs:subClassOf D), (D rdf:type A),  => (C rdf:type A)]` - if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @AKSW: Thanks for your reply. Could you please let me know the exact difference between rdfs:subClassOf & rdfs:type? I checked the documentation, its not so clear.    
`[(s rdf:type C), (C rdfs:subClassOf D) => (s rdf:type D)]`  
`[(s rdfs:subClassOf C), (C rdfs:subClassOf D) => (s rdfs:subClassOf D)]`

Comment: As per my requirement there are hierarchy of classes (SubClass2) and I want to make all those classes of type "SubClass1". What is the exact way to do that? I dont want to assign rdf:type to all the classes as (child1 rdfs:type SubClass2). I am looking for inference way of solution.

Comment: `rdfs:subClassOf` is used as a relationship between classes, while `rdf:type` is used to assert an individual to a class.

Comment: @AKSW: Thanks. Could you please tell me the what was the way to implement my use case (at least using different predicate). I know that I can use `rdfs:subclass`, but I don't want to make `SubClass1 parent of SubClass2`.